# Count Workbooks in VBA and close Excel if Count > 1

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count

How to close a specific Excel file if someone opens a new Workbook for Excel?

This is what I have:

```
If Workbooks.count > 1 Then
    Application.Visible = False
End If
```

I saved it and then close it and then open the file back up then hit crtl+n for a new instance of Excel and nothing happens. Am I missing initial code for it to active the count function?

Comment: The first thing to learn (with any programming language), is how to efficiently research. "vba close Excel workbook" should give you ideas. `Application.Visible = False` merely makes Excel *invisible*, it doesn't close anything. Also Ctrl+N creates a new *workbook*, not a new instance of Excel. See task manager / processes, look for EXCEL.EXE ;-)  ...that said I've no idea what your question might be. Did you read [ask]?

Comment: Yes, I know there is a close function and visibility function. I'm honestly not too particular on either. Yes CRTL+N does create a new workbook so the count would be greater than 1 at that point, so I would want to close/hide the application so no one is able to copy the data over to another excel sheet.

Comment: You need to handle the `WorkbookOpen` even at application level, if you want code to run when a workbook is opened. If you want to run code when a *new* workbook is created, you need to handle the `NewWorkbook` event, again at application level.

Answer (score 0):

To close the active workbook programmatically, you can do:

`If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    Workbooks("Put the name of the workbook you want to close here").Close
End If`

Application.Visible = False does not close the workbook, but hides the application.

Also, if you are looking to create a new instance of Excel, you can do:

`Dim objExcel As Object
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: So that is something that I already wrote but just for checking i put it back in there. I saved the file again and then hit CRTL+N to open another workbook but it did not close the original file. So it seems like it is not running the code. Is it possible that I might have some setting that is prohibiting it from running? I wish I could upload a picture to show you what I see.